Why aren't my views found in .NET 4.8 routing?
On my system we're using ASP.NET MVC with cshtml. I have a controller that should return a view based on his name. The software was made on Portuguese so I have:
AgendamentoConfirmacaoiController -> agendamentoConfirmacao(token) -> View(agendamentoConfirmacao)

My path is:
Areas/AgendamentoSQ/view/AgendamentoConfirmacao/agendamentoConfirmacao

The Map.Route is:
Map.Routes("AgendamentoSQ",
           "AgendamentoSQ/{controller}/{action}%26{queryParams}",
           queryParams = UrlParameters.Optional)

AgendamentoConfirmacaoiController:
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("agendamento-confirmacao/confirmar")]
    public ActionResult agendamentoConfirmacao(string token)
    {
        if (token.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
        {
            return Json("Ação concluída", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        var result = AgendamentosServicoBL.confirmarAgendamento(token);

        var viewModel = new ConfirmarAgendamentoForm
        {
            confirmacao = true,
            sucesso = result.Length == 0,
            mensagem = result
        };

        return Json("Ação concluída", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

View
@model WEB.Areas.AgendamentosSQ.Models.ViewModels.ConfirmarAgendamentoForm

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Confirmação de Agendamento</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: #f4f4f4;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        .confirmation-container {
            background-color: #ffffff;
            border-radius: 10px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            text-align: center;
            padding: 40px;
            max-width: 400px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .confirmation-icon {
            font-size: 50px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .confirmation-message {
            font-size: 18pt;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .confirmation-details {
            font-size: 12pt;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        .button-link {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            font-size: 12pt;
            font-family: Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
            color: #ffffff;
            text-decoration: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        .success {
            color: #00853E;
        }

        .success .confirmation-icon {
            color: #00853E;
        }

        .success .button-link {
            background-color: #00853E;
        }

        .success .button-link:hover {
            background-color: #006B2E;
        }

        .error {
            color: #D62828;
        }

        .error .confirmation-icon {
            color: #D62828;
        }

        .error .button-link {
            background-color: #D62828;
        }

        .error .button-link:hover {
            background-color: #A32020;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="confirmation-container @(Model.sucesso ? "success" : "error")">
        <div class="confirmation-icon">
            @(Model.sucesso ? "✔️" : "⚠️")
        </div>
        <div class="confirmation-message">
            @(Model.sucesso ? "Ação confirmada com sucesso!" : "Token Expirado!")
        </div>
        <div class="confirmation-details">
            @(Model.sucesso ? (Model.confirmacao ? "Seu agendamento foi confirmado com sucesso!" : "Seu agendamento foi cancelado com sucesso!") : Model.mensagem)
        </div>
        <div>
            @(Model.sucesso ? "" : "É necessário a confirmação do agendamento com 1 hora de antecedência ao passar disso o agendamento é CANCELADO!")
        </div>
        <a href="/" class="button-link">
            @(Model.sucesso ? "Voltar à página inicial" : "Solicitar novo agendamento")
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Routes
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace WEB
{
    public class RouteConfig {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}

I tried to change the action hoping it would work, but nothing has worked.
I tried to check the view path and he method name but nothing...
I hope when I call the controller I receive the View with the data.

You're not returning your view. Instead you're returning raw JSON data. See: how-controllers-specify-views

Is there an error message that you can include to make it more clear what the problem is?

You should return View(viewModel)
